# Unable to upload file using Angular/Spring

Tags: angular, spring, multipartform-data, angular-httpclient

The title says it all.

I need to upload files/documents to BE, somehow I just cant get it right!

**Angular service**

```
public saveFile(file: File): Observable<any> {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);
        
        return this.http
            .post<FormData>(`${environment.apiUrl}/save-file`, formData)
            .pipe(first());
    }
```

**Spring Controller**

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/save-file")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> saveFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

        System.out.println(file);

        return null;
    }
```

I have already tried a lot of other configuration, like set headers to

```
"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
```

The error message is always the same:

```
Current request is not a multipart request
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your request body is instanceof FormData angular add that header for you . and you dont need to add header .

i think you have interceptor configuration to add some header to all your http requests.
try to add this conditions to your interceptor class :

```
        if (!request.headers.has("Content-Type") && !(request.body instanceof FormData)) {
            request = request.clone({
               headers: request.headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json")
            });
        }
```

Comment: Amazing deduction mate. Right in the spot! Thank you so much!!!